# SQL Server SUM stored procedure to get values for months that have no values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Ok, first of all Hi to all developers out there,

This question I have been strugling really hard, I have a stored procedure that gets the debt from my clients per month and I am displaying it on my dashboard, so if I have 0 documents that are unpaid for 1 month then I dont get that month shown on my chart.

Basically I want to have the chart for the current year, like right now we are in July I want it to display months from january to July and if there are months that have 0 as debt then I want the result to deploy a 0.

I paste my stored actual procedure so I have some pointers from more experienced developers out there, I have searched already for this but I cant figured it out very well, thank you very much in advance.

```
SELECT
        DATENAME(MONTH, [Documents].[Date]) AS 'Name',
        SUM([Documents].[Balance]) AS 'Value'
    FROM 
        [Documents]
    WHERE
        [Documents].[Balance] <> 0 AND
        [Documents].[MovementType] = COALESCE(@movementType, [Documents].[MovementType])
    GROUP BY
        DATENAME(MONTH, [Documents].[Date])
```

Comment: Easiest way is to use or create a `months` table and then you can use an `outer join`.

Comment: And what do you expect when your Documents table has been in use for more than a year? Do you want rows for January 2018 and January 2019 to be counted together? Do you assume that your table is purged monthly to avoid this issue? Is that a safe assumption?

Comment: I will change to stored procedure just to get data for current year, The historical data will remain but the chart will just get the data for current year.

Answer (score 0):

I can be achieved by using `COALESCE`and `Table Value Constructor`:
'Table Value Constructor' is supported in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or later:

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(MONTH, [Documents].[Date]) AS 'Name',
    COALESCE(SUM([Documents].[Balance]), 0) AS 'Value'
FROM 
    [Documents]
RIGHT JOIN 
  (Select v.valueId From (values ('January'), ('February'), ('March'), ('April'), ('May'), ('June'), ('July'), ('August'), ('September'), ('October'), ('November'), ('December')) v(valueId)) as vm 
  on vm.valueId = DATENAME(MONTH, [Documents].[Date])
WHERE
    [Documents].[Balance] <> 0 AND
    [Documents].[MovementType] = COALESCE(@movementType, [Documents].[MovementType])
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(MONTH, [Documents].[Date])
```

Note: I haven't tested it but it should work

Comment: This is the error I get when using this: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'February' to data type int.

Comment: Change 1,2,3 to 'January', ;February like that;

Comment: Ok changing that works to make the procedure work but it still doesnt show the months that have 0 as the sum.

Comment: Have you used the right join. For that it must show you the 12 records even if we do not have matching records

Comment: Can you share the table schema and sample records?

Comment: the table is pretty simple, the balance is over 0 if there the document is not paid completely, and 0 when its completely paid off. it would be a pretty large schema to share i believe but the only column I care about if the balance.

Comment: If you share the sample schema and data and it would be good for us to create such thing in our local and check it.

Answer (score 0):

this may work also...

```
DECLARE @MONTH TABLE(Month INT)
DECLARE @COUNT INT

SET @COUNT = 0

WHILE @COUNT <> 12
BEGIN
 SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1
 INSERT INTO @MONTH VALUES (@COUNT)
END

 SELECT m.Month AS 'Name',SUM(ISNULL([Documents].[Balance],0)) AS 'Value'
 FROM @MONTH m
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [Documents] ON m.Month = DATEPART(Month,[Documents].[Date])
 WHERE [Documents].[Balance] <> 0 AND
  [Documents].[MovementType] = COALESCE('', [Documents].[MovementType])
 GROUP BY  m.Month
```